# Python dataframe groupby binning statistics

Tags: python, dataframe, mean, pandas-groupby, binning

For each "acat" unique value, I want to count how many occurrences there are of each "data" category (call this "bins"), and then calc the mean and skew of "bins"

possible values of data = 1,2,3,4,5

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'acat':[1,1,2,3,1,3],
                   'data':[1,1,2,1,3,1]})


df
Out[45]: 
   acat  data
0     1    1
1     1    1
2     2    2
3     3    1
4     1    3
5     3    1
```

for acat = 1:

bins = (2 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0)
average = bins / 5 = 0.6

for acat = 2:

bins = (0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0)
average = bins / 5 = 0.2

for acat = 3:

bins = (2 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0)
average = bins / 5 = 0.4

bin_average_col
0.6
0.6
0.2
0.4
0.6
0.4

Also I would like a bin_skew_col.

I have a solution that uses crosstab, but this blows my PC memory when the number of acat is large.

I have tried extensively with groupby and transform but this is beyond me!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show an example of your skewness calculation?

Comment: Yes, hopefully this will help.  If I take acat1 as an example:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'bin_for_acat1':[2,0,1,0,0]})

df1.skew()
   1.257788